# Why does the amplitude, bandwidth and position of Gaussian change when data changes from positive to negative

Tags: normal-distribution, matlab, regression-coefficients, goodness-of-fit, r-squared

I'm trying to fit a single Gaussian to some values in Matlab. When the values are positive, the model fits without any issues. However, when these values become negative, the r squared value changes, as do the amplitude, bandwidth and position of the Gaussian. Can anybody help me understand why this happens?

The amplitude, bandwidth and position of the Gaussian should be the same regardless of whether it is in the positive or negative direction, yet these values appear to change.

To illustrate, I fit a single Gaussian to this data containing positive data points:

```
times = 1:10;
data = [0,0,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,0];
[coeff,gof] = fit(times',data','gauss1');
```

This gives me the following coefficients and goodness of fit values:

coeff =

```
 General model Gauss1:
 coeff(x) =  a1*exp(-((x-b1)/c1)^2)
 Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
   a1 =       3.776  (3.418, 4.133)
   b1 =       6.001  (5.812, 6.189)
   c1 =       2.445  (2.177, 2.713)
```

gof =

```
       sse: 0.3253
   rsquare: 0.9823
       dfe: 7
adjrsquare: 0.9773
      rmse: 0.2156
```

However, when I make the data variable negative, all the coefficients and goodness of fit values change, even though the relationship between all my data points is the same.

To illustrate:

```
data = data * -1;
[coeff,gof] = fit(times',data','gauss1');
```

This produces these values:

coeff =

```
 General model Gauss1:
 coeff(x) =  a1*exp(-((x-b1)/c1)^2)
 Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
   a1 = -1.256e-168
   b1 =      0.8233
   c1 =        0.11
```

gof =

```
       sse: 44
   rsquare: -1.3913
       dfe: 7
adjrsquare: -2.0745
      rmse: 2.5071
```

Can anybody explain why this is the case and where I am going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Do the quotes in `',data'` matter in Matlab syntax?

Comment: @EdM The ' after data and time transposes these variables so they change from row vectors to column vectors. You have to input column vectors into the fit option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This didn't happen when I tried (it converged to correct solution), but this is a nonlinear optimization and you could help it along by supplying starting values. Here's how you can do that:

```
[coeff,gof] = fit(times',-data','gauss1','start',[-1 5 2])
```